# Break lines in g.drawString in Java SE

Tags: java, drawstring

This is exactly what I'm trying to do:

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 5));
g2.setPaint(Color.black);
g2.drawString("Line 1\nLine 2", x, y);
```

That line prints like this:

```
Line1Line2
```

I want it like this:

```
Line1
Line2
```

How can I do this in `drawString` ?

As well as how can I do a tab space for a line??

Comment: See `LabelRenderTest.java` via [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7775713/418556).  The trick is to use HTML in a styled component such as a `JLabel`, then render the label.

Comment: how to use JTestArea for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
       private void drawString(Graphics g, String text, int x, int y) {
                for (String line : text.split("\n"))
                    g.drawString(line, x, y += g.getFontMetrics().getHeight());
            }

       private void drawtabString(Graphics g, String text, int x, int y) {
            for (String line : text.split("\t"))
                g.drawString(line, x += g.getFontMetrics().getHeight(), y);
        }


            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 5));
            g2.setPaint(Color.black);
            drawString(g2,"Line 1\nLine 2", 120, 120);
            drawtabString(g2,"Line 1\tLine 2", 130, 130);
```

Comment: As well as how can I do a tab space for this??

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0300__SWT-2D-Graphics/Drawstringanddisplaynewlinesandtabsasnonprintablecharacters.htm

Comment: private void drawtabString(Graphics g, String text, int x, int y) {
            for (String line : text.split("\t"))
                g.drawString(line, x += g.getFontMetrics().getHeight(), y);
        }

Comment: Can you please tell me how to combine those to codes. (Line breaker and tab space)

Comment: Working on something that may utilize your solution, what does `String text` represent here?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet I used to draw text in a `JPanel` with tab expansion and multiple lines:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class Scratch {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
                graphics.drawRect(100, 100, 1, 1);
                String message =
                        "abc\tdef\n" +
                        "abcx\tdef\tghi\n" +
                        "xxxxxxxxdef\n" +
                        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxghi\n";
                int x = 100;
                int y = 100;
                FontMetrics fontMetrics = graphics.getFontMetrics();
                Rectangle2D tabBounds = fontMetrics.getStringBounds(
                        "xxxxxxxx",
                        graphics);
                int tabWidth = (int)tabBounds.getWidth();
                String[] lines = message.split("\n");
                for (String line : lines) {
                    int xColumn = x;
                    String[] columns = line.split("\t");
                    for (String column : columns) {
                        if (xColumn != x) {
                            // Align to tab stop.
                            xColumn += tabWidth - (xColumn-x) % tabWidth;
                        }
                        Rectangle2D columnBounds = fontMetrics.getStringBounds(
                                column,
                                graphics);
                        graphics.drawString(
                                column,
                                xColumn,
                                y + fontMetrics.getAscent());
                        xColumn += columnBounds.getWidth();
                    }
                    y += fontMetrics.getHeight();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(400, 200);
            }
        };
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();

        frame.setVisible(true);    }
}
```

It really seemed like [`Utilities.drawTabbedText()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Utilities.html#drawTabbedText(javax.swing.text.Segment,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Graphics,%20javax.swing.text.TabExpander,%20int)) was promising, but I couldn't figure out what it needed as input.