# How to draw on a buffer with Undo capability?

Tags: java, swing, buffer, jpanel, graphics2d

While I am not doing some animation or drawing a very complicated graphics.
I need (sort of) double buffering for drawing several primitives. In the application, user enters name of Shape followed by related arguments and that shape is drawn on buffer, and then on screen.
Eg of a command is `RECT 100, 50, 200, 120`.

For persistence, I can store all commands in list and in
`public void paintComponent(Graphics g)` of JPanel I draw them one by one.
But this is highly inefficient, because of iterating through list and using a hash map each time to call (or dispatch) the relevant shape-drawing-interface.

How and on what type of buffer can I draw? How can different methods draw on this buffer?

Additionally is there a convenient way to be able to undo previous draws with buffer? Or do I need to redraw on buffer each time a undo is done?

Thanks, I don't want full code, but relevant class names and small pseudocode is appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your criteria for _efficient_? `List<Shape>` typically suffices for thousands of shapes.

Comment: @trashgod: There should not be flickering, and moreover drawing each time the application is switched, should not require to draw everything inside paintComponent.

Comment: *"should not require to draw everything"*  Research 'premature optimization'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Sorry, but my last experience (of drawing breadboard) was not very good. So I got a little more worried.

Comment: *"So I got a little more worried."*  You should post a little [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Well I had nothing to post as SSCCE, the above example I solved by using wxWidgets library with C++(so no point posting it) and this time around as you pointed out, it was _Research 'premature optimization'_. But I completely agree with you, I almost always try to post SSCCE, so as to make my question answerable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`JPanel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) is double buffered by default, so selecting and dragging are typically quite smooth. [`GraphPanel`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel) is a simple object drawing program that illustrates such operations on a `List<Node>`. A similar approach has been successfully used with thousands of nodes.

The details of implementing an *undo* strategy depend significantly on the desired behavior, but `remove()` and `repaint()` are effective.

Addendum: One common optimization for rendering large numbers of objects uses the [flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern). [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), [`JFreeChart`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) and [`JGraph`](http://www.jgraph.com/) are examples. This simplified [`example`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7776211/230513) illustrates the essential mechanism.

Comment: NB: `remove()` should should be done via the corresponding `ListIterator`.

Comment: +1 for this nice example, though I forgot to put my comment before. It might will help me learn the basics of drawing :-)