# Reorder panels in scroll-pane 

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

Currently I'm having a container to list all the (`JPanel`) panels in a scroll pane. The function that I'm trying to accomplish is trying to reorder the panels. For example: moving the 2nd panel to the first, then moving the 3rd panel to the last spot.  Currently I'm thinking using the Containers Index and moving them in the data layer.

What is a good way to represent the moving in the GUI form?

The only idea I have is putting up and down arrows in on the panel. Which doesn't look so pretty, and very messy when you have like 100+ panels.

Comment: How about Drag-and-Drop?

Comment: Hi Grey, i looked up the DnD libraries, but I'm not too confident. I've been looking up examples where you can drag and drop panels. But most examples are Drag and Drop Texts.

Comment: Is the updation of the `JPanel` happening too often ? if not, you can use an `ArrayList` to store `JPanel`s then and add them again to your `JFrame` when you know whom to move and where :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two general approaches to reorder a [collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/reference.html) of `JPanel` instances in response to an event:

- Change the *actual* order of the panels in the container by removing them all, altering the order, validating the enclosing container and repainting; this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3078354/230513) shows the basic idea for `JLabel` instances.
- Change the *apparent* order of the panels in the view using the [flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) and a [tabular renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender); this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7776211/230513) shows the basic idea using `CellRendererPane`.