# Dynamically changing content visibility in JPanel inside JScrollpane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have a JPanel inside JScrollPane. Inside the JPanel are numerous JButtons. However, these JButtons are set to NOT VISIBLE (jbutton.setVisible(false)) when the JPanel and JScrollPanel are initialized. The JButtons are only set to VISIBLE (jbutton.setVisible(true)) when another class triggers this.

However, although these JButtons are getting successfully added and set to visible on the JPanel, they are not visible on the JPanel or JScrollPane. My guess is that when the JScrollPane adds the JButtons, the JButtons are set to NOT VISIBLE, and even if the JButtons are set to VISIBLE, the JScrollPane does not detect they are.

Is there a way of dynamically changing the visibility of the JButtons in the JPanel inside the JScrollPane?

Comment: Share some code so we have a better idea of what you are doing. It shoulda like your "adding" the panel to the scroll pane instead of setting the scroll pane's viewport's view

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Maybe use a `CardLayout` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, although these JButtons are getting successfully added and
>   set to visible on the JPanel, they are not visible on the JPanel or
>   JScrollPane. My guess is that when the JScrollPane adds the JButtons,
>   the JButtons are set to NOT VISIBLE, and even if the JButtons are set
>   to VISIBLE, the JScrollPane does not detect they are.

- have to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` to `JPanel`, as last code lines after all changes are executed
- have to change [`setUnitIncrement`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11183706/714968) for `JButtons` in `JPanel` wrapped in `JScrollPane`, because scrolling is too slow, isn't natural

Comment: I've been calling repaint and revalidate to both the JPanel and the JScrollPanel as last code lines. Hasn't worked...

Why do I have to change the setUnitIncrement for JButtons...? I can scroll through the panel well, it's just my Jbutton isn't showing up..

Comment: Sounds like possible layout issue

Comment: then there musst be another issue, nothing clear from your question, hmmmm oooooonly are the JPanel added as JScrollPane.setViewportView(JPanel), otherwise for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Comment: `Why do I have to change the setUnitIncrement for JButtons`, please blue colored are link to another post or www sites, did you read linked post, tried code example

Comment: Yes, I have, and it doesn't fix my problem. Will look into this a bit more.