# How to get line height for a font, like in JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtextarea, fontmetrics

I need to get distance from baseline of one line to baseline to next text line, the same as it is laid out in JTextArea. For that, I have only a font with specified font size.

My problem is that on font, I can only get LineMetrics or FontMetrics, and they both have different sizes of line (getAscent/getHeight/getDescent) depending on the current text - for example, if there is letter `f`, the ascent is bigger, and if there is `g`, I have descent.

Is there a way to get "global" font height property? So I will be able to draw text on Graphics2D properly.

Comment: You might find a `GlyphVector` to be of more utility, as mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6296381/418556).  Another approach is to put the entire text in an HTML formatted label then use the preferred size of the label as the width/height of the resulting text, as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7775713/418556).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From JavaDoc for [`FontMetrics.getHeight()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html#getHeight%28%29):

> Gets the standard height of a line of text in this font. This is the
>   distance between the baseline of adjacent lines of text. It is the sum
>   of the leading + ascent + descent. Due to rounding this may not be the
>   same as getAscent() + getDescent() + getLeading(). There is no
>   guarantee that lines of text spaced at this distance are disjoint;
>   such lines may overlap if some characters overshoot either the
>   standard ascent or the standard descent metric.

So if your fonts are implemented correctly, this should be the distance you should put between two lines of text.

Comment: How can I instantiate a FontMetrics object? The class itself is abstract.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: you get it from your `Graphics` object: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#getFontMetrics-java.awt.Font-

Comment: An alternative (easier?) way to get FontMetrics is the getFontMetrics() method from JComponent. Something like:  myTextArea.getFontMetrics(myTextArea.getFont())