# Swing components twitch when resizing JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, window-resize

I have an undecorated `JFrame` which has a lot of `components` inside it (such as `JSplitPanes`, `JPanels with GridBagLayouts, BoxLayouts, BorderLayouts` etc). The code of building this `JFrame` is **2500** lines length, so I wouldn't place it here, or it's simpled version, sorry.

When I drag the `JFrame` by `right` or `bottom` side, it resizes OK, but when I drag it by `left` or `top` side, the `components` inside the `JFrame` are **twitching** a lot, so it looks very ugly.

**My question is:** Why does it happen? How can I prevent it (if I can)? Does anyone fix that in own practice?

**UPD:** I've written my own resizer for `JFrame`. It works OK for other windows, which have less amount of components.

Comment: please how is possible that `undecorated JFrame` can caused `JFrame by right or bottom side, it resizes OK`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resizing the frame implicitly validates the enclosed `Container`, which causes `doLayout()` to be invoked on the affected components each time the size changes. You can see a similar effect in repeated calls to `paintComponent()` when resizing this [`AnimationTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3256941/230513). As you observe, using thousands of components scales poorly. As an alternative, leverage the [*flyweight pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) to render only visible cells, as is done in `JTable`, `JTree`, `JList`, etc. If you can't use one of these, `CellRendererPane`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7776211/230513), may help.

Comment: How can apply *flyweight pattern* to `JSplitPane`?

Comment: You'd also need to do implement editors, and you _may_ be able to work on just a subset of components; [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) to be sure; note that `invalidate()`, "needs to execute quickly."