# Performance issues when checking if tile is in camera view java swing

Tags: java, swing, perlin-noise

I am making a tile based Game, i generate a random map using perlin's noise. When my map is 100 * 100 tiles it works fine but when my map is 1000 * 1000 tiles i get performance issues, I solved most of these by checking if my tiles were in the camera's view than drawing them but it is still buggy. Here is some of my code :

Loading

```
void loadMap(int size)
{
    blocks.clear();
    float[][] seed1 =  Perlin.GenerateWhiteNoise(size, size);
    float[][] seed = Perlin.GenerateSmoothNoise(seed1, 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < seed.length; i++)
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < seed[i].length; j++)
        {
            if(seed[i][j] < 0.5)
            {
                blocks.add(new Block(i * Block.blockSize, j * Block.blockSize, eBlockType.WATER));
            }

            else if(seed[i][j] > 0.8)
            {
                blocks.add(new Block(i * Block.blockSize, j * Block.blockSize, eBlockType.GRASS));
            }

            else
            {
                blocks.add(new Block(i * Block.blockSize, j * Block.blockSize, eBlockType.SAND));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Drawing

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    cameraX = -player.getX() + getWidth()/2;
    cameraY = -player.getY() + getHeight()/2;
    g.translate(cameraX, cameraY);
    for(Block block : blocks)
    {
        //System.out.println(block.getX() + " " + cameraX);
        Rectangle cameraView = new Rectangle(-(cameraX+cameraPadding), -(cameraY+cameraPadding), this.getWidth()+cameraPadding , this.getHeight()+cameraPadding);
        if(cameraView.contains(block.getX(), block.getY()))
        {
            block.draw(g2);
        }

        else if(block.getX() > cameraView.getMaxX() && block.getY() > cameraView.getMaxY())
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    player.draw(g2);
}
```

Block Class

```
package com.ymail.sanchixx.game;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Block
{

    enum eBlockType
    {
        NULL(-1), STONE(0), STONEBRICK(1), // these are collision
        COLLISION_BLOCKS(2), // PlaceHolder
        GRASS(3), PLANK(4), WATER(5), SAND(6); // these are non-collision

        private int code;

        eBlockType(int c) 
        {
            code = c;
        }

        public int getCode() 
        {
            return code;
        }
    };

    eBlockType m_type = eBlockType.NULL;
    int m_x;
    int m_y;
    static int blockSize = 16;

    Block(int x, int y, eBlockType type)
    {
        m_x = x;
        m_y = y;
        m_type = type;
    }

    boolean isNonCollisionBlock()
    {
        if(m_type.getCode() > eBlockType.COLLISION_BLOCKS.getCode())
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    static boolean collisionDown(Entity e, int v)
    {
        Rectangle player = new Rectangle(e.getX(), e.getY() + v, e.getWidth(), e.getHeight());
        for(Block i : Game.blocks)
        {
            if(!i.isNonCollisionBlock())
            {
                int blockWidth = blockSize;
                int blockHeight = blockSize;
                Rectangle block = new Rectangle(i.getX(), i.getY(), blockWidth, blockHeight);
                if (player.intersects(block))
                {
                    e.setY(e.getY() - (e.getY() - (i.getY() - e.getHeight())));
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    static boolean collisionUp(Entity e, int v)
    {
        Rectangle player = new Rectangle(e.getX(), e.getY() -v, e.getWidth(), e.getHeight());
        for(Block i : Game.blocks)
        {
            if(!i.isNonCollisionBlock())
            {
                int blockWidth = blockSize;
                int blockHeight = blockSize;
                Rectangle block = new Rectangle(i.getX(), i.getY(), blockWidth, blockHeight);
                if (player.intersects(block))
                {
                    e.setY(e.getY() - (e.getY() - (i.getY())) + blockHeight);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    static boolean collisionRight(Entity e, int v)
    {
        Rectangle player = new Rectangle(e.getX() + v, e.getY(), e.getWidth(), e.getHeight());
        for(Block i : Game.blocks)
        {
            if(!i.isNonCollisionBlock())
            {
                int blockWidth = blockSize;
                int blockHeight = blockSize;
                Rectangle block = new Rectangle(i.getX(), i.getY(), blockWidth, blockHeight);
                if (player.intersects(block))
                {
                    e.setX(e.getX() - (e.getX() - (i.getX() - e.getWidth())));
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    static boolean collisionLeft(Entity e, int v)
    {
        Rectangle player = new Rectangle(e.getX() - v, e.getY(), e.getWidth(), e.getHeight());
        for(Block i : Game.blocks)
        {
            if(!i.isNonCollisionBlock())
            {
                int blockWidth = blockSize;
                int blockHeight = blockSize;
                Rectangle block = new Rectangle(i.getX(), i.getY(), blockWidth, blockHeight);
                if (player.intersects(block))
                {
                    e.setX(e.getX() - (e.getX() - (i.getX())) + e.getWidth());
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    static Boolean swimmingInBlock(Entity e, eBlockType type)
    {
        Rectangle player = new Rectangle(e.getX(), e.getY() + e.getHeight()/2, e.getWidth(), e.getHeight()/2);
        for(Block i : Game.blocks)
        {
            if(i.isNonCollisionBlock())
            {
                int blockWidth = blockSize;
                int blockHeight = blockSize;
                Rectangle block = new Rectangle(i.getX(), i.getY(), blockWidth, blockHeight);
                if (player.intersects(block))
                {
                    if(i.getType() != type)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    eBlockType getType()
    {
        return m_type;
    }

    int getX()
    {
        return m_x;
    }

    int getY()
    {
        return m_y;
    }

    void draw(Graphics g)
    {
        switch(m_type)
        {
        case GRASS:
            g.drawImage(Game.blockImg[0], m_x, m_y, null);
            break;
        case WATER:
            g.drawImage(Game.blockImg[4], m_x, m_y, null);
            break;
        case SAND:
            g.drawImage(Game.blockImg[6], m_x, m_y, null);
            break;
        case STONE:
            g.drawImage(Game.blockImg[1], m_x, m_y, null);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're still visiting N<sup>2</sup> tiles to test for visibility, even if you choose to render only certain tiles. Instead, use the [flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) to render only visible tiles, where visibility can be determined solely by panel/tile geometry. The approach, outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7776211/230513), is used to optimize `JTable`.