# Swing: JScrollPane causing render issues

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

Sometimes (not always) when scrolling the bar of my JScrollPane, some of the components (usually the text ones like JLabels) don't repaint properly and they end up only being partially rendered.

I don't know why this is. I've tried invoking paint() inside of an AdjustmentListener, but that doesn't seem to help.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Initialization of the components

```
    panel = new JPanel();
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("editor.png");
    setIconImage(img.getImage());
    initComponents();

    final JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(panel);
    this.setContentPane(pane);
    //pane.setLayout(new ScrollPaneLayout());
    //pane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    Dimension dim = panel.getSize();
    dim.height = dim.height - 100;
    pane.setSize(dim);
    this.setSize(dim);
    AdjustmentListener hListener = new AdjustmentListener() {
        @Override
        public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
            repaint();
            for(Component c : panel.getComponents())
                c.repaint();
            for(Component c : pane.getComponents())
                c.repaint();
            panel.repaint();
            panel.revalidate();
            pane.repaint();
            pane.revalidate();
        }
    };
    pane.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(hListener);
    panel.setVisible(true);
    pane.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: can you post some code please ?

Comment: The posted code does not reproduce the problem, and nor can I see it suggesting the cause of the problem. Consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Well I'm not really sure what to do, I don't want to post my entire initcomponents(), it'll be way too big. Besides what I've posted, I just initiate the components and add them to 'panel'

Comment: And we don't want to see your entire code either. Consider cutting back on your code until you have isolated the problem.

Answer (score 8):

Violations of any of these basic principles can cause rendering artifact.

- Verify that Swing GUI objects are constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
- Ensure that you honor the [opacity](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#props) property. In particular, `JLabel` is *not* opaque by default.
- "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#callbacks).

Addendum: Incorporating these dicta, this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6118633/230513) scrolls thousands of flashing `JLabel` instances without artifact.